# How to read integers from a text file containing symbols, numbers and maybe alphabets?

Tags: c++, ifstream

How to read integers from the following text file containing symbols, numbers and maybe alphabets?

I have the following text file

```
@
100:20 ;
20:40 ;
#

@
50:30 ;
#

@
10:21:37 ;
51:23 ;
22:44 ;
#
```

I have tried the following codes :

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream myfile("10.txt", std::ios_base::in);

    int a;
    while (myfile >> a)
    {
       std::cout<< a;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and

```
void main()
{
   std::ifstream myfile("10.txt", std::ios_base::in);
   std::string line;

   while (std::getline(infile, line))
   {
       std::istringstream iss(line);
       int n;
       while (iss >> n)
       {
         std::cout << n ;
       }

    }
}
```

All I get is a garbage value of int variable (or the initial value if I initialize it )

How to solve this?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To read the integers from the text file I have written

Comment: try reading a string, instead of an int, in your example. You'll find out that you need a little bit more tuning to get what you want

Comment: I have tried that too. But how to know which one are integers and which one are symbol and alphabets. The integers in file do not have any specific range

Comment: Your file has structure. [Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) it.

Comment: if you *need* to know if it's a digit, look at `std::isdigit`. But, as already noted, you don't need this, since your file *has* a structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try splitting each line into separate tokens delimited by the colon character:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream myfile("10.txt", std::ios_base::in);
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(myfile, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        std::string token;
        while (std::getline(iss, token, ':'))
        {
            std::istringstream tss(token);
            int n;
            while (tss >> n)
            {
                std::cout << n << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This should print:

```
100
20
20
40
50
30
10
21
37
51
23
22
44
```

As per this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31271199/how-to-read-integers-from-a-text-file-containing-symbols-numbers-and-maybe-alph#comment50537497_31271199), I recommend a more robust parsing algorithm that respects the unique structure of your files.

Comment: how do you know which integers belong to which pair of @ and # ?

Comment: My answer doesn't know, but presumably the author was stuck on this specific part of his problem, and wanted relief for that specific issue. Hopefully the author can press on with a more advanced parsing algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Try skipping bad character one after another

Something like:

```
while (!in.eof())
{
   int a;
   in >> a;
   if (!in) // not an int
   {
     in.clear(); // clear error status
     in.ignore(1); // skip one char at input
   }
   else
   {
     cout << a;
   }
 }
```